# How to define a foreign key in JPA entity?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I have a query for Customer table creation.

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
 `cus_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `phone` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`email`)
)
```

I have the second table which is the booking table query with a foreign key of email which is from customer table.

```
CREATE TABLE `booking` (
 `booking_num` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `pass_email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `contact` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`booking_num`),
 CONSTRAINT `email_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`pass_email`) REFERENCES `customer` (`email`)
)
```

How do I make the JPA to create the tables that performs the exact query for creation of tables?

what would be in the @JoinColumn annotation and the relationship?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you start with a good tutorial, or scour this site looking for examples.  When you get stuck, post the relevant code in your question.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations